# React native app doesn't connect to VPN server in android

Tags: react-native, android-vpn-service

I developed a mobile app which is connected to APIs with axios. It was working fine before. But now those APIs can only be accessed through an VPN because server is restricted. So, I connected to the VPN with mobile and accessed those APIs URL successfully with the browser. But with the VPN on, I can't access the same APIs through mobile app. It doesn't allow me. Since, I can access them from browser, I think, VPN connection is okay, its working good in iOS but android only i faced issues

I am excepting i want a solution how to configure android in react native